# how to detect free space around object

Tags: objective-c, object, cgrect

i've got few objects in view and i want to detect if space (for ex. `[myObject frame] - 5px`) is free.

now i must detect when my object is clicked but how can i detect free space?

```
NSString *currPuzzle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentPuzzle];
currentObject = [puzzleArray objectForKey:currPuzzle];
currentObjectFrame = [currentObject frame];
currentObjectCenter = [currentObject center];

int left = currentObjectFrame.origin.x - 1;
int right = currentObjectFrame.origin.x + 1;
int top = currentObjectFrame.origin.y - 1;
int bottom = currentObjectFrame.origin.y + 1;
```

i've got no idea how solve it.

any idea?

Comment: do you really need to detect "free space", every time an object is clicked, you know it wasn't in that free space ?

Comment: yes. i see objects, i click in one and i must check if space on left is available to move this object in this free space

Comment: the frame property is a `NSRect` relative to the superview's coordinates system. If you know the superview's frame, you are able to compare with your objects' frames.

Comment: Basically, you have to materialize the entire view and check each object's bounds.  Not especially hard.

Comment: ok i resolve it. i create temporary rectangle and i detect intersect with this rect. all work great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i resolve it. i create temporary rectangle and i detect intersect with this rect. all work great.